# Rendering a list of HTML elements with data returned by server

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, async-await

I have an array of objects returned by the server which I have to display in a table. I tried using array.map() method to map the the objects as row elements into another array and then displaying that array in the JSX like `<tbody>{listItems}</tbody>`

```
const TeacherTable = () => {
  let listItems
  async function getTeacherData() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1234/api/teacher')
    const res = await response.json()
    console.log(res.data)
    listItems = await res.data.map(record => (
      <tr>
        <td>{record.teacherID}</td>
        <td>{record.teacherName}</td>
        <td>{record.teacherEmail}</td>
      </tr>
    ))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getTeacherData()
  })
  return <tbody>{listItems}</tbody>;
};
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I doesn't seem to work. I tried to console.log() the data array to check if the data is getting passed to the frontend and its getting through without any errors but still the list doesn't get rendered.

How do I render this list of row elements from the array?

Thank you for reading this far. Hope you have a great day/night ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you should do:

1. `listItems` needs to be a state variable meaning that it causes a re-render of the component when it gets updated, because right now when `listItems` is set inside of `getTeacherData` the component isn't re-rendering. I've implemented it as state in the updated code below (called `items` now). If you want to read more about state and how it causes updates you should check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) out
2. You should pass an empty array as dependencies to `useEffect`. The short explaination as to why is because you only want `useEffect` to be called once, for a more thorough explaination you should read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).
3. Kinda building off (1), it's arguably a better practice to have state only contain data and not the component logic. In this example you'll see that I didn't map out the fetched data as jsx, rather I just stored it's contents and mapped it out inside the return part of the component.

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const TeacherTable = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  
   useEffect(() => {
      async function getTeacherData() {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1234/api/teacher')
            const res = await response.json()
            console.log(res.data)
            setItems(res.data);
        }

        getTeacherData();
    }, []);
  
  return <tbody>{items.map(record => (
      <tr>
        <td>{record.teacherID}</td>
        <td>{record.teacherName}</td>
        <td>{record.teacherEmail}</td>
      </tr>
    ))}</tbody>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I'll implement it now and see if this works. Thank you again

Comment: It worked and the list is getting rendered. Thank you so much